# Javascript String to date conversion without date format but passing locale

Tags: javascript

I have this user input date field, where user can enter date as string such '010117' or '01012017' which I am converting to US date standard format(MM/dd/yyyy) using JavaScript. If we have to go international we want user to input date as string as per their country standard.

Question is, Is there any library for JavaScript that we can use to pass the date as string and locale and it will convert the string to their locale standard date format.

We don't want to pass date format for each country as it will be too much of a task to do that  for each country.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is JavaScript library [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com) which provides very good features about date and time.
We can pass the string to MomentJS and  it will give date.

By default MomentJS comes with English locale. You can change the locale by passing locale string to below function:

`moment.locale(myLocale);`

To get user's locale, you can do the following:

`var myLocale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;`

Refer to the the link:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: I have seen this moment.js .
So here is the deal, my application is running in different country, user can enter date based on their locale, such as Turkey (31.3.17) I want to validate the date and return the full date as 31.03.2017, I don't want to format date for each and every country. So how can I achieve that in Moment.js